# Asking for an alternative to Drupal is a right question?

Tags: support

Just wondering if I can I post a question like this:

> ...I need to develop a Forum. I have 2 options: 1)Drupal 2)phpbb.
>
> Which are the pro and cons of these 2 option? ...

I know there is no a correct and single answer for this one, but the answer will come from someone which has some Drupal knowledge though.

Comment: FWIW, there was a discussion either here or on DA about a similar question wrt. forums.  I cannot find the link right now, though.  Some searching may dig it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too broad. There isn't just a single correct answer, or there could be a single answer that considers all the possible scenarios, which would not be probably helpful to future readers.

Such questions are reported between the questions you should not ask, in the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq).

> Comparison between Drupal and other CMS's, blog software, or similar software

Comment: that´s clear. thanks.